# Java Enrollment register

Tags: java

I have to write a program using java to store and manage    a   set of  students    enrolled    on  a   course. 
For each student, their name, date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy),address and gender should be   stored.
The  program needs  to   enable  students to be  added to the course or deleted from the course. And the    program user must be able to search  for a student by name (Assuming the name is unique).

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {

private String name;
private String address;
private String gender;
private String dob;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public Student(String sName, String sAddress, String sGender, String sDob) {
    name = sName;
    address = sAddress;
    gender = sGender;
    dob = sDob;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the students name");
    name = in.nextLine();
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the students address");
    address = in.nextLine();
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the students gender");
    gender = in.nextLine();
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the students DOB");
    dob = in.nextLine();
}

}

public class student_tester {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Student student01 = new Student ("", "" ,"", "");
    student01.setName(null);
    student01.setAddress(null);
    student01.setGender(null);
    student01.setDob(null);

    Student student02 = new Student ("", "" ,"", "");
    student02.setName(null);
    student02.setAddress(null);
    student02.setGender(null);
    student02.setDob(null);

}
}
```

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am unsure how I can search for students and delete them

Comment: `setName(String name)` This parameter has the same name as a field variable. `name = in.nextLine()` is not setting a value for the field variable; it's setting the value for the local parameter variable. Changing it to `this.name = in.nextLine()` (same with your other methods) should hopefully fix your problem. You should just remove the parameter, and you need to use `this` to reference the field variable

Comment: check my answer to restructure and implement search and delete methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice is to  Maintain a unique identifier field such as Student ID in the Student class. You can maintain a List in your driver program i.e student tester with the main method .
Make sure you read the input in your tester class or driver class and not in student class. So you can keep adding each student object to the list.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
     public class student_tester {

public static void main (String [] args) {
 List<Student> allStudents =new ArrayList<Student>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true){
    Student student01 = new Student ();
  System.out.println("Please enter the students name");
    student01.setName(in.nextLine());
  System.out.println("Please enter the students address");
    student01.setAddress(in.nextLine());
  System.out.println("Please enter the students DOB"); 
    student01.setDob(in.nextLine());

 System.out.println("Please enter the students gender"); 
    student01.setGender(in.nextLine());
}
}
```

you should read input in the tester class and loop through to keep adding new students as the user inputs.

For search on the basis of a field  :

eg Search and delete on giving a student's name.

```
   public Student search( String studentName){

    foreach(Student s : allStudents)
    if(s.getName().equals(studentName){

// you can return this student object or print his other details 
// System.out.println(s.getAddress()); etc
       return s;
    }
    return null;
    }
    }
```

for delete :

```
public void delete(String studentName)

foreach(Student s : allStudents)
if(s.getName().equals(studentName){

    allStudents.remove(s);   
}

}
}
```

You can remove the constructor with 4 paramters in the Student class. And change all the setters as per:

;

```
public class Student {


 // private String id  .. maybe
private String name;
private String address;
private String gender;
private String dob;

//for clarity
public Student(){

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setName(String name) {
   this.name=name;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
  this.address=address;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender=gender;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
   this.dob=dob;
}

}
```